# building REST API in FLASK

Tags: rest, flask

A very basic question. I have a FLASK app which has postgresql behind it. There are no ORM for this application. All requests are done via SQL psycopg2 interface.

Now I want to expose certain API's from this application. What would be the best way to proceed.

1> Just like: http://flask-peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rest-api.html
2> or can I do one without the ORM. It seems that ORM for an RESTful API is very useful but in this case I have to have a separate database elements and copy data from the postgres model to the ORM.

any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: Did you look at Flask-RESTful:http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/?

Comment: you are right on spot. Just after the comment above ..settled on flask restful. ALso using module apibase to help with some error handling classes. (http://blog.selfassembled.org/posts/api_base.html ). But what I am worried is the error handling. Does flask restful provide good error handling of exceptions....?

Comment: I really didn't use Flask-RESTful, but try look at http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending.html#custom-error-handlers

Answer (score 7):

I have a similar setup Flask + Postgres and PsycoPG2. 
I followed the following tutorials to design and implement the API
I handle errors manually and respond with the appropriate HTTP code

http://blog.luisrei.com/articles/rest.html { Design API}

http://blog.luisrei.com/articles/flaskrest.html { Implement API}

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [Flask-Restless](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org) is a better choice. Validations, authentication support are much simpler with it.

Answer (score 3):

For non-trivial applications better use flask-classy. Flask-Restless is somewhat limiting, and flask-restful doesn't really give much over flask-classy, besides being more complex.
I personally used flask-restless for some time before moving to flask-classy.

Comment: Flask-classy isn't maintained anymore unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

There is bunch of different frameworks on top of flask now.

- http://python-eve.org/index.html
- http://www.flaskapi.org/

Answer (score 0):

**REST API in FLASK and Postman app:**

**Code:**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,jsonify,json
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras


app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy()

conn = psycopg2.connect("postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/country")
cr = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def test():

    return jsonify({
        'message': 'Welcome'
    })


@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return "<h1>404</h1><p>The resource could not be found.</p>", 404


##### Countries ######
@app.route('/country/all', methods=['GET'])
def country():

   cr.execute('select * from country')
   country = cr.fetchall()
   countries = []
   for row in country:
       countries.append(dict(row))
   return jsonify(countries)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

**Result:**

[image]**